# I can't find the typo in my syntaxhighlighter code. Can you spot it?

Tags: powershell, syntax-highlighting

On my Blogger blog I have the following code exactly, but it doesn't work.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeRDark.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true; 
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = &#39;http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/clipboard.swf&#39;;
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script> 
<script language='javascript' src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js'/>
<script language='javascript' src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPowerShell.js'/>
```

Here is how I call the PRE tag:

```
<pre class="brush: powershell">
   @echo off
   dir C:\temp
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you referring to `SyntaxHighlighter` before you include the script that defines it?

It looks like you need to put the `<script src=...>` lines at the top.